# How to create "native 32 bit" application?

Tags: c#, metasploit

I am using shellter in my kali linux and want to inject a file using the software? I created a Simple Calculator in C# using visual studio with plateform x86 and release mode while compiling. But still shellter shows error that it only support "native 32 bit applications only".
What i am doing wrong? I compiled 32 bit in my visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not a linux-pro and do not know what shellter is but i guess in this case native means the application must be native as a cpp-application. dotnet and java as examble are not native because the are compiled to bytecode on build and then compiled to machine code at runtime. so i think you have to write your application in a language which builds machine code as c++ does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write native applications in C#.

Shellter is a "AV Evasion Artware" product and it probably rewrites parts of the applications code by disassembling it and using different instructions (but with the same end result) to assemble it back together.

.NET applications are compiled to a intermediate language (Common Intermediate Language (CIL), formerly called Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL)) and they are interpreted (and possibly compiled to native code) on the end-users machine. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

> During compilation of CLI programming languages, the source code is translated into CIL code rather than into platform- or processor-specific object code. CIL is a CPU- and platform-independent instruction set that can be executed in any environment supporting the Common Language Infrastructure, such as the .NET runtime on Windows, or the cross-platform Mono runtime.

You need to write your application in C/C++ or Delphi if you want to produce a real native application that contains machine instructions that are executed directly by the CPU.